# React + Tailwind component library import issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, create-react-app

I tried creating a Component library in react + tailwindcss. When I am doing npm run storybook, things seem to work fine in my stories with my components.

Consequently i did an npm publish, and tried to import it to another app. I am getting this error, when I do an npm run start there.

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (19:5):

  17 |
  18 |   const Single = ({ title, content, show, index }) => (
> 19 |     <div
     |     ^
  20 |       key={title}
  21 |       className={`justify-between single-row ${classNameRow || ""}`}>
  22 |       <div

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

Here is the code to this specific component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

import ChevronDown from "../../icons/chevronDown.svg";

const Accordion = ({
  className,
  classNameRow,
  classNameRowTitle,
  classNameRowContent,
  content
}) => {
  const [contentState, setContentState] = useState(
    content.map(row => ({ ...row, show: Boolean(row.show) }))
  );

  const Single = ({ title, content, show, index }) => (
    <div
      key={title}
      className={`justify-between single-row ${classNameRow || ""}`}>
      <div
        className={`flex flex-row justify-between cursor-pointer single-row-title ${
          classNameRowTitle || ""
        }`}
        onClick={() => {
          setContentState(
            contentState.map((contentRow, rowIndex) => ({
              ...contentRow,
              show: rowIndex === index ? !contentRow.show : contentRow.show
            }))
          );
        }}>
        {title}
        <img
          src={ChevronDown}
          className={`transition-transform duration-400 ${
            show ? `transform rotate-180` : `rotate-0`
          }  `}
        />
      </div>
      <div
        className={`${
          show ? "h-auto py-2 " : "h-0"
        } single-row-content ${classNameRowContent}`}>
        {content}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <div className={`${className || ""}`}>
      {contentState.map((row, index) => (
        <Single
          key={row.title}
          title={row.title}
          content={row.content}
          show={row.show}
          index={index}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Accordion;
```

This is my babel config

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
};
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

UPDATE:

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = ({ config, mode }) => {
  /* PostCSS Support */
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.css$/,
    loaders: [
      // Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS
      {
        loader: "postcss-loader",
        options: {
          /* 
            Enable Source Maps
           */
          sourceMap: true,
          /*
            Set postcss.config.js config path && ctx 
           */
          config: {
            path: "./.storybook/"
          }
        }
      }
    ],

    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
  });

  // Return the altered config
  return config;
};
```

UPDATE: This was a babel config issue. You also need a compat config. Follow this tutorial https://www.madelyneriksen.com/react-component-library-tutorial/

Comment: Have you set up for babel to run in the storybook files in your webpack config?

Comment: Hi Ryan, 

The storybook is running fine. When I'm importing the library elsewhere, that is causing the issue.

Comment: I see, The error message that you are getting "Support for the experimental syntax JSX isn't currently enabled" indicates that your imported code does not go through babel. So I think it's necessary to double-check your webpack config if it's covered storybook file type to transform JSX syntax.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have edited my question with the webpack config. I think the only config I have added is postcss for tailwind. Do you have any useful reads/recommendations on how to add babel?

Comment: Try this to see if it works for you: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11671#issuecomment-692789715. Add these lines if you have your story book file extention as *.MDX    {
        test: /\.mdx?$/,
        use: ['babel-loader', '@mdx-js/loader']
      },

Comment: I think you're right in that the code I've written in the imported component is not going through babel. Given your above answer, it leads me to believe the problem is not with storybook, but with the webpack.config.js of the library. I tried adding the module.rules from the above answer to the webpack.config of the library, no change though

Comment: Can you may be share your github repo url or at least a minimal repo that has your current config so may be I can take a look deeper?

Comment: https://github.com/Pikkol/beatle-ui This is the UI component library repo.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t figure out any thing else with this repo alone. May be you will need to check your target repo where you import this to.

Comment: Hey, so I followed this tutorial and recreated the repo https://benjaminwfox.medium.com/creating-a-react-component-library-by-abstracting-a-react-component-library-45290114d22a 

This is working now. I'm unable to understand why though.

Comment: Good to hear that, try compare them together maybe you find something.